# iOS 5 'Facial Recognition' for objects

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

I'm trying to figure out a way to use the facial recognition software within iOS 5 to detect objects.  Currently, I'm using Xcode 4.2 and have a sample of code from here: http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/

I would like to redefine what "eyes" and "mouth" is to allow the app to distinguish objects.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Face detection algorithms typically work by searching for image features (e.g, certain patterns of gradients) that are specific to the human face. They cannot be used to detect other arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are no public APIs for modifying the face detector. You will have to find other image processing software to detect your non-face objects.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Open CV. It should be able to do object recognition. Here is a post about building it for iPhone. http://lambdajive.wordpress.com/2008/12/20/cross-compiling-for-iphone/